# Issues with beforeunload not preventing refresh/closing

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, onbeforeunload, typeform

Trying to prevent closing/refreshing with beforeunload and an embedded typeform but it doesn't seem to display the warning message. Is there something I'm missing?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
        event.returnValue = "";
      });
    </script>
    <div class="relative pt-16 m-auto overflow-hidden" style="height: 700px">
      <iframe
        id="typeform-full"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="camera; microphone; autoplay; encrypted-media;"
        src="https://form.typeform.com/to/AQlHXdch?typeform-medium=embed-snippet"
      ></iframe>
      <script>
          type="text/javascript"
          src="https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js"
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved with overscroll-behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using Chrome?

The ability for a page to specify the onbeforeunload string was removed in Chrome 51. (It was also removed by Safari starting with Safari 9.1 and in Firefox 4.)
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

Comment: I am indeed. Is there any other way to warn the user of loss of data that works with current versions of browsers?